# Extract number of variable length from string

Tags: regex, bash

I want to extract a number of variable length from a string.

The string looks like this:

```
used_memory:1775220696
```

I would like to have the `1775220696` part in a variable. There are a lot of questions about this, but I could not find a solution that suits my needs.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can use `cut`:

```
my_val=$(echo "used_memory:1775220696"  | cut -d':' -f2)
```

Or also `awk`:

```
my_val=$(echo "used_memory:1775220696"  | awk -F':' '{print $2}')
```

Answer (score 6):

Use parameter expansion:

```
string=used_memory:1775220696
num=${string#*:}              # Delete everything up to the first colon.
```

Comment: Note that this will also work in any POSIX-compliant shell, not just `bash`.

Answer (score 5):

I used to use egrep

```
echo used_memory:1775220696 | egrep -o [0-9]+
```

**Output:**

```
1775220696
```

Answer (score 2):

use the regex:

```
s/^[^:]*://g
```

you use it with sed or perl and get the part you needed.

```
> echo "used_memory:1775220696" | perl -pe 's/^[^:]*://g'
1775220696
```

Answer (score 2):

`bash` supports regular-expression matching, but for a simple case like this it is overkill; use parameter expansion (see [choroba's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16015665/1126841)).

For the sake of completeness, here's an example using regular expression matching:

```
[[ $string =~ (.*):([[:digit:]]+) ]] && num=${BASH_REMATCH[2]}
```

Answer (score 1):

Can be done using awk, like this:

```
var=`echo "used_memory:1775220696" | awk -F':' '{print $2;}'`
echo $var
```

**output:**

```
1775220696
```

Answer (score 0):

If your number could be anywhere in the string, but you know that the digits are contiguous, you can use shell parameter expansion to remove everything that is not a digit:

```
$ str=used_memory:1775220696
$ num=${str//[!0-9]}
$ echo "$num"
1775220696
```

This works also for `used_memory:1775220696andmoretext` and `123numberfirst`. However, something like `abc123def456` would become `123456`.