# Algorithm to extract number of varying length from title of file

Tags: python, string, algorithm, pseudocode

I have a list of 400,000 file names (column in excel) of the format

> xxx.Number.Date.zzz.txt

and I want to extract the Number from the string

Normally I would just set it to take the 5th through 9th character in that string, but the numbers vary in length (2 - 4 digits) and I am not sure how to design an algorithm that can tell how long the number is.

Using python3 if anyone is interested, but really I just need help with the pseudocode

I looked at this previous question, but it did not really answer the question in terms that I can use since it seems like it is using bash functions or I did not understand the explanation:

[Extract number of variable length from string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16015590/extract-number-of-variable-length-from-string)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If the format of the file is always `xxx.Number.Date.zzz.txt`, and we only care about `Number`, then you could convert the string into a list, and then extract the 1st element of that list. Example:

```
file = "xxx.4432.Date.zzz.txt"
num = file.split(".")[1]
print(num) # prints 4432
```

You could write this in a loop to go through your Excel column (check out [openpyxl](https://openpyxl.readthedocs.io/en/stable/) if you haven't yet).

Answer (score 3):

You can use a regular expression (available in most languages):

```
.*?\.(\d+)\.
```

which matches the number between the first two dots:

```
import re
re.match('.*?\.(\d+)\.', 'xxx.12345.Date.zzz.txt').group(1)
#'12345'
```

---

An explanation on [`regex101`](https://regex101.com/r/fc5Frw/1).

---

This can also be done in pure Python (easily translatable to other languages):

```
s = 'xxx.12345.Date.zzz.txt'
out = ''
in_num = False
for c in s:
    if in_num:
        if c == '.':
            break
        out += c
    elif c == '.':
        in_num = True
```

giving `out` as: `'12345'`.

*Note that with this second method, we do not verify that the characters between the first fullstops are digits.*